# I'm writing a book and am wondering what punctuation is invalid for such "statement"?

Tags: punctuation

I can't give you the details of the book because I'm currently writing it and it's not something I'd like to discuss. But I'll give you the paragraph here.

> ONE moment. That’s all it takes for everything to change forever.
>   That’s all it took to change me forever. After all, isn’t that what
>   we’re all after? Time? We want time, so that we can write our wrongs.
>   We want time so that we could turn it all around and make things right
>   again, in our lives, or in the lives of those we love. We want time,
>   because it’s the only thing that tells us the truth. We want time
>   because it has the ability to heal us from the damage one moment has
>   caused us.

I feel like the commas and some other punctuation are either too much or missing. Is my paragraph missing anything? Is there too much of one thing? Lack of punctuation? How would I properly write that with the correct punctuation?

Comment: "write our wrongs":  pun intended?

Comment: Lol, no. People make mistakes in their lives so they want to write their wrongs by doing something good for  a change. Is it spelled wrong or something?

Comment: You right wrongs; you write about wrongs.

Comment: There's a spelling mistake, a typo, that's what deadrat's trying to tell you: [*to right a wrong*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/right-a-wrong) means to correct something, to put the record straight, but *to write a wrong [word]* means to incorrectly write (spell) a wrong [word]

Comment: Lol. Well, that's embarrassing. I didn't realize by definition at least, that the spelling was wrong until you pointed it out. For example, write your history. I thought it had more to do with an apology or maybe symbolism. Thanks for telling me the difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Punctuation can help us read something as if we were hearing it spoken. From that point of view your prose reads well. It sometimes pauses me for a moment's reflection; it sometimes rushes ahead with an appropriate urgency; and it does not unnaturally stop me in the wrong places. Stay with it and trust yourself.